# Do until populating string with comma separated values

Tags: vb.net, arrays, populate

Hey all i am trying to populate an array like so:

```
Dim tmpArray As String = ""

Do Until x = Form1.arrayCal.Length
    tmpArray = tmpArray & "," & x
    x += 1
Loop

tmpArray = Replace(tmpArray, ",1", "1")

Dim arrDaysInMonth As String() = {tmpArray}
```

Dim arrNumOfVisits As Double() = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 52, 20, 20, 10, 35, 3, 8, 47, 7, 2, 5, 55, 8, 0, 0, 6, 55, 0, 2, 12, 0, 0, 21, 14, 0, 3}

```
    Me.ChartControl1.Series.Clear()
    Dim s As New DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Chart.Series()

    s.Type = DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Chart.ChartType.Bar2D
    s.Points.DataBindXY(arrDaysInMonth, arrNumOfVisits)
```

However, it does not seem like i can do it that way.. Doing it this way seems to put it only in a 1D array and not {1,2,3,4,5...} type of array as it needs to be in.

Any help would be great!

David

Comment: Umm, you don't have *any* arrays here...?

Comment: Dim arrDaysInMonth As String() should be an array, i guess

Comment: Corrected that. It should be a String.. but the same situation still presists.

Comment: Look at `String.Join()` method to create a string array of the form "1,2,3.." easily.

Comment: Please be more clear on what you need to have in the end. Do you need a string with comma separated values, do you need an array of strings or do you need something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want can be accomplished by this:

```
    Dim daysCount As Integer = 31
    Dim arrDaysInMonth As String() = New String(daysCount - 1) {}

    For index As Integer = 0 To arrDaysInMonth.Length - 1
        arrDaysInMonth(index) = (index + 1).ToString()
    Next

    ' arrDaysInMonth(0) = "1"
    ' arrDaysInMonth(1) = "2"
    ' ...
```

Or maybe you want this:

```
    Dim arrayCal As String = "1,2,3,4,5,6"
    Dim tmpArray As String() = arrayCal.Split(","c)

    ' tmpArray(0) = "1"
    ' tmpArray(1) = "2"
    ' ...
```

Comment: You got it by the first example there, ja72. Thanks! :o)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to use an array if you want to create it dynamically, you should use collections as they are much quicker and they are saving resources:

```
Dim array As New System.Collections.ArrayList

Do Until x = Form1.arrayCal.Length
   array.Add(x)
   x += 1
Loop
```

You can also access the elements of the ArrayList by index.

By the way: your version is not working, because you would need to compile and run your code that it is working.

This

```
Dim arrDaysInMonth() As String = {"1,2,3"}
```

is not the same like this

```
Dim arrDaysInMonth() As String = {"1","2","3"}
```

Comment: It needs to be in this format **Dim arrDaysInMonth() As String = {"1,2,3"}** in order to work.

Comment: this is exactly what you have now. An array with one element.

Comment: When i get to this point in the code **s.Points.DataBindXY(arrDaysInMonth, arrNumOfVisits)** i get the error **Index was outside the bounds of the array.**.

Comment: The arrDaysInMonth and arrNumOfVisits - Its xValues() As Object, ParamArray yValues()() As Doubles.

Comment: Please review your question. You are referring to code which is not in your question.